# ASUS X101CH Shuts Down During BIOS Update

Tags: bios

I'm updating the BIOS of my ASUS X101CH Eee PC netbook using a flashable DOS-based utility from the ASUS website and in the middle of the update I accidentally moved the socket outlet away from the pluged in charger and without the battery it'll turn off immedietly.

Now it doesn't display anything and there's no keys functioning after boot, literally just a BLACK screen.

Can I fix this all by myself without handing over my netbook?

Comment: BIOS things are tricky. I can't say for sure, but you may have bricked your device. Someone may know better but you may need to send it in.